# Truncate overflow text in table cell, so table does not go wider than screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display various items in tabular format (each entry has various attributes). The following is also required:

1. Columns should be dynamic so as to closely fit content, no fixed widths (handled by table layouts)
2. Rows should be clickable to activate an action on that row's entry, e.g. show new page with expanded version of that content (handled by using CSS `display: table/table-row/table-cell` instead of `<table>/<tr>/<td>` - as per example code). (Another reason for me is that I use JSF, which generates HTML, but sort of leaves me stuck with with using this.)
3. **I am unable to get this right**: The table should not grow outside the screen width if possible. In particular, a "summary" column displays (potentially long) text, which is to be truncated when necessary, so text fits into the cell, which is adapted to the table width, which may not be wider than screen width.

   - I use the CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis` on this summary, together with other needed settings. Because the surrounding `<div>` already has `display: table-cell`, while the `ellipsis` attribute [needs an inline/block element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow), the "summary" text is wrapped in another `<div>`.

Here is an example of the **desired** effect (note NO scrollbar at bottom):
[image]

While this is what I am currently able to achieve (***NOT ideal***) (note scrollbar at bottom - which indicates table runs off window on right):
[image]

Here is barebones code to achieve this (one could omit all attributes marked with `/*l&f*/` (look and feel), they are only meant to generate a cleaner-looking, easier to debug example).

**CSS and HTML:**

```css
A {
  /*l&f*/text-decoration: inherit;
  /*l&f*/color: inherit;
}
.list-table {
  display: table;
  /*l&f*/border: 1px solid blue;
  /*l&f*/border-spacing: 5px;
}
.list-tr {
  display: table-row;
  /*l&f*/background-color: lightgray;
}
.list-td {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap; /* one line */
  /*l&f*/padding: 2px; border : 1px solid green;
  /*l&f*/border: 1px solid red;
}
.summary {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap; /* one line */
  overflow: hidden; /* make text overflow */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* truncate tex with ... */
  /*l&f*/background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-table">
  <a href="#1" class="list-tr">
    <div class="list-td">Row 1</div>
    <div class="list-td">More stuff</div>
    <div class="list-td">
      <div class="summary">Some single line run on text goes here</div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#2" class="list-tr">
    <div class="list-td">Row 2</div>
    <div class="list-td">Other column</div>
    <div class="list-td">
      <div class="summary">This is text content that runs on and on
        and on without end and may need to be truncated somewhere on the
        summary screen depending on screen size to show only the first part
        that will fit.</div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#3" class="list-tr">
    <div class="list-td">Row 3</div>
    <div class="list-td">Still other content</div>
    <div class="list-td">
      <div class="summary">Here is still more long text that may
        need truncation in the summary version because it is so long.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have been able to achieve the desired result with `display: -moz-box` (and various other `-moz-` settings), in the `summary` style. Not happy because this is not cross-platform.

Do you have any better suggestions? Your help is much appreciated :-)

Comment: You can use [other box stylings](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) as well as mox-box to gain your cross browser compatibility

Comment: @Aravona, it seems dicey in this case since other browsers' "experimental" features don't correspond **exactly**, also has been superceded by `flex`, which again differs.... Will however see if `flexbox` gives any joy, not familiar with it at the moment.

Comment: It was mostly since you're already trying the moz-box this was just the first hit for browser compatibiltiy. There's probably more - just google :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can make changes to your exported HTML then you have here a possible solution.

I made a few changes to your HTML (added a parent div to `.summary`, to create a fixed table by using `table-layout:fixed`)

See **SNIPPET** below:

```css
A {
  /*l&f*/
  text-decoration: inherit;
  /*l&f*/
  color: inherit;
}
.list-table {
  display: table;
  /*l&f*/
  border: 1px solid blue;
  /*l&f*/
  border-spacing: 5px;
  width: 100%; /* ADDED */
}
/* CREATED */
.fixed-table {
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display:table
}

.list-tr {
  display: table-row;
  /*l&f*/
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.list-td {
  display: table-cell; /* CHANGED */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* one line */
  /*l&f*/
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /*l&f*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.summary {
  display: table-cell;
  /*l&f*/
  background-color: lightblue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* one line */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* make text overflow */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* truncate texT with ... */
}
```

```html
<div class="list-table">
  <a href="#1" class="list-tr">
    <div class="list-td">Row 1</div>
    <div class="list-td">More stuff</div>
    <div class="list-td">
      <div class="fixed-table">
        <div class="summary">Some single line run on text goes here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#2" class="list-tr">
    <div class="list-td">Row 2</div>
    <div class="list-td">Other column</div>
    <div class="list-td">
      <div class="fixed-table">
        <div class="summary">This is text content that runs on and on and on without end and may need to be truncated somewhere on the summary screen depending on screen size to show only the first part that will fit.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#3" class="list-tr">
    <div class="list-td">Row 3</div>
    <div class="list-td">Still other content</div>
    <div class="list-td">
      <div class="fixed-table">
        <div class="summary">Here is still more long text that may need truncation in the summary version because it is so long.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, useful to know :-) Just tested in IE11, Opera34, Firefox41, Chrome47 (seems I need to update...). Useful further tweaks if others need to do similar: `border-collapse: collapse` in **fixed-table** to, well,  collapse the borders :-), `min-width: ` *something acceptable, e.g. 4em* in **summary** to prevent that column collapsing totally on very narrow screens (will allow scroll to right in this case, which is OK).

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-table {
  max-width:100vw;
}
```

Comment: Seems `max-width: 100vw` (or `100%`) still grows the view area larger than the screen if content warrants it. At least on Firefox, will test others later.

Answer (score 0):

About all I could do was add (an arbitrary) `max-width` to your `summary` class:

```
.summary {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap; /* one line */
  overflow: hidden; /* make text overflow */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* truncate tex with ... */
  /*l&f*/background-color: lightblue;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

You'll need to give `.summary` some kind of non-inherited width to get `text-overflow` to work I think...